# Problema no acesso à API Json com React

Tags: javascript, json, react, async, async-await

Estou tentando acessar a seguinte variável no Json de uma API:

```
page[0].infoBloco[0].tabela[0].dados[0].fonte.nome
```

Estou recebendo o erro:

```
TypeError: this.state.page[0] is undefined[Learn More] index.jsx:49
```

O Json que a API retorna é o seguinte:

```
[
    {
        "infoBloco": [
            {
                "tabela": [
                    {
                        "dados": [
                            {
                                "fonte": {
                                    "url": "http://www.google.com",
                                    "nome": "Site de buscas"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "infoBloco": [
            {
                "tabela": [
                    {
                        "dados": [
                            {
                                "fonte": {
                                    "url": "http://www.yahoo.com",
                                    "nome": "Outro site de buscas"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

O código da página React é o seguinte:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

export default class extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      page: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3003/api')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ 
        ...this.state, 
        page: data,
      }))
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.state.page[0].infoBloco[0].tabela[0].dados[0].fonte.nome)

    return (
      <div>
        Exemplo
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Eu só consigo acessar até page[0], quando tento acessar qualquer elemento mais interno retorna esse mesmo erro. Esse erro seria causado pelo acesso assíncrono à API? Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir isso?

`console.log(this.state.page)` retorna o json completo [image: Print]

`console.log(this.state.page[0])` retorna o primeiro objeto do json [image: Print]

`console.log(this.state.page[0].infoBloco)` gera o erro `TypeError: this.state.page[0] is undefined[Learn More] index.jsx:49` [image: Print]

Comment: Faz só `console.log(page);`, que resultado dá? Não deveria ser `console.log(this.state.page);`?

Comment: `this.state.page` retorna o json completo, a partir de `this.state.page[0].infoBloco` é que aparece o erro `TypeError: this.state.page[0] is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em react, para acederes a objectos/valores que estão no `state` de um componente, deves usar `this.state`, no teu caso seria `this.state.page`

Comment: Realmente eu havia esquecido de colocar o this.state aqui no stackoverflow, mas o código original está como console.log(this.state.page[0].infoBloco[0].tabela[0].dados[0].fonte.nome) e retorna esse mesmo erro. Muito obrigado pela observação!

Comment: E se fizeres `console.log(this.state.page);`? O array está vazio? Ou não é nem um array?

Comment: `this.state.page` retorna um array completo com os dois objetos json. 
`this.state.page[0]` retorna o primeiro objeto do array.
`this.state.page[0].infoBloco` retorna o erro `TypeError: this.state.page[0] is undefined`

Comment: Adiciona o output a pergunta de quando fazes `console.log(this.state.page)`, estranho dar erro só quando acessas a uma propriedade do `page[0]`

Comment: Só para constar o recomendado pela documentação é mesmo usar `setState` e não atribuir o estado diretamente. Isso irá fugir a certos casos especificos que podem dar em bugs particulares.

Comment: No código delete, ele tem a chamada ao `setState`, mas o problema pode estar ai sim. Gostava de ver o que tem o `page` para tentar perceber. Pode também ser de ainda não ter recebido a resposta a API quando faz o render, e estar a tentar aceder a índices no array que ainda não existem, mas ai `this.state.page[0]` não devia retornar o objecto que ele está a espera.

Comment: Ok, adicionei um link com o print logo após `console.log(this.state.page)` na pergunta original

Comment: Aparentemente está a fazer log 2 vezes, pelo output da consola. Isso será então o que mencionei no comentário acima, a primeira vez que entra no `render`, o resultado da chamada a API ainda não retornou.

Comment: E como posso fazer para o resultado ser exibido só após ser recebido da api? tenho que usar algum outro código ou middleware?

Comment: Podes por um if no `render`, tipo `if (this.state.page.length === 0)`. Também podes mudar o teu `.then` que tem o `setState` e fazer `setState` para colocar no state apenas o que precisas, em vez da raiz do objecto (`pages`). Se não precisas de usar o caminho especifico como tens no exemplo, em que usas só 1 dos items, o melhor é fazer ciclos para listar tudo, se estiverem vazios nada renderiza, mas quando há dados, vai funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Funcionou, estou verificando com if, mostrando uma mensagem de load e quando page está preenchido eu renderizo o componente. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Solução fornecida por Leite

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

export default class extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      page: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3003/api')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ 
        ...this.state, 
        page: data,
      }))
  }

  render() {

    //soluciona o problema do preenchimento da variável page
    if (this.state.page.length === 0) return <div>Loading, please wait…</div>

    return (
      <div> 
           Exemplo: {this.state.page[0].infoBloco[0].tabela[0].dados[0].fonte.nome}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```